# Using launchctl in from NSTask

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstask, launchd

I want to execute `launchctl` from application.

For that I am using following code,

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/launchctl"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"load ", @"/Users/XYZ/com.XYZ.plist", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

[task launch];
```

It gives me error, `launchctl: unknown subcommand "load "`

However, when I run command from terminal, it executes correctly

```
>launchctl load /Users/XYZ/com.XYZ.plist
```

Whats the difference here and how can it work NSTask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the trailing space in `@"load "`.

Each object in the array is a single argument for the task. There is no need
to add spaces to separate the arguments (or to quote the arguments).

Comment: I felt like doing little suicide. :D